# Read semi-structured text file in R

Tags: r

I have a tab delimited text file that I'd like to read into R. The file is what I would call "semi-structured" - that is, most of the file consists of data frames (300+) of identical size (32*30), with colnames and rownames. On the line preceding each data frame there is a unique id for that data frame (ID1... etc.), and there is a blank line between each data frame.

I tried reading the file into R with the following:

```
read.table(file = "my.file", header = TRUE, sep = "\t",
    na.strings = " ",  blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
```

which worked fine, but the entire file is read as being levels in a single factor. Ideally, i'd ultimately like the data in a list, with each data frame an element in the list, and the unique IDs as keys for each list element. Here's an example of just two matrices from the start of the file read in with the above command (although they are represented as a single factor, the shape of the data is the same as in the text file). Any ideas on how I can read this in and reshape into a list?

```
Ind <- structure(list(ID.1 = structure(c(2L, 43L, 41L, 39L, 37L, 35L, 
33L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 22L, 20L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 
15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 43L, 42L, 40L, 38L, 36L, 34L, 32L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 
24L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("", "       66.5E 67.5E 68.5E 69.5E 70.5E 71.5E 72.5E 73.5E         74.5E 75.5E 76.5E 77.5E 78.5E 79.5E 80.5E 81.5E 82.5E 83.5E 84.5E 85.5E 86.5E 87.5E     88.5E 89.5E     90.5E 91.5E 92.5E 93.5E 94.5E 95.5E 96.5E 97.5E", 
"  8.5N                                                               0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                                      ", 
"  9.5N                                                               0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                                ", 
"  ID=2", " 10.5N                                                         0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0       0.0                                                                                                                    ", 
" 11.5N                                                         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                                ", 
 " 12.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0           0.0                                                                                                          ", 
" 13.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0            0.0                                                                                                          ", 
" 14.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0           0.0                                                                                                          ", 
" 15.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0           0.0                                                                                                          ", 
" 16.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                          ", 
" 17.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                    ", 
" 18.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                              ", 
" 19.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                        ", 
" 20.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                  ", 
" 21.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                      ", 
" 22.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                         0.0                              ", 
" 22.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.3   0.0   0.0   0.0        0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                          0.0                              ", 
" 23.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0       0.0                        ", 
" 23.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   1.5   0.3   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0       0.0                        ", 
" 24.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                  ", 
" 24.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.9   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                  ", 
" 25.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   2.2   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                  ", 
" 25.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.6   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                  ", 
" 26.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0        0.0            ", 
  " 27.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   0.0", 
" 28.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0        0.0   0.0                                       0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0        0.0   0.0   0.0", 
" 29.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0        0.0                                                                                 0.0       0.0   0.0      ", 
" 30.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0           0.0                                                                                                          ", 
" 31.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                                ", 
" 31.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   2.9   4.6       4.5                                                                                                                ", 
" 32.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                                 ", 
" 32.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.2   5.4       4.2                                                                                                                ", 
" 33.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                                ", 
" 33.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.9   0.7       2.5                                                                                                                ", 
" 34.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                                ", 
" 34.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.4   0.6       1.5                                                                                                            ", 
" 35.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0                                                                                                          ", 
" 35.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.2   0.4   1.0       1.6                                                                                                           ", 
 " 36.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0       0.0                                                                                                                ", 
" 36.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.3       0.6                                                                                                                ", 
"     37.5N                                                                                                                                                                                                    "
), class = "factor")), .Names = "ID.1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-64L))
```

(In the read data, the row names all line up - I messed this up indenting the code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `skip` and `nrows` arguments to `read.table` to control which portions of the file are read.

```
start_rows <- seq(2, by = 35, length.out = 300)
data_list <- lapply(start_rows, function(skip) 
{
  read.table(<as before>, skip = skip, nrows = 32) 
})
```

You can get the names of the datasets in a similar way using `scan`.

```
name_rows <- start_rows - 1
data_names <- sapply(name_rows, function(skip) 
{
  scan(the_file, character(), n = 1, nlines = 1, skip = skip)
})
names(data_list) <- data_names
```

---

As a minor code tidying point, consider swapping `read.table` for `read.delim`, since you appear to be using a tab delimited file.

---

As Spacedman pointed out, there are speed issues with this solution.  I don't know if they will be a big problem with that much data, but it certainly won't scale too well.  One solution is to have a preprocessing step where you use `readLines` to read everything in, then repeated call `writeLines` on each block of lines with data.
That way each data frame is saved in its own file, and you can work with them as normal.

Comment: note the skipping will get linearly slower as R has to skip larger and larger chunks of the file...

Comment: @Richie Cotton. Thanks a lot - I managed to get the data read in and into a list of dataframes. There is still one problem, however. Each data frame in the list has 30 rows and only 1 column. Somehow all the data have been squished into one column (though the data *look* correctly laid out on screen. Any ideas?

Comment: All the data in one column usually means that you have the wrong value for `sep`.  Maybe you used `\t` and it is really spaces, or the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

If your file really is neatly arranged in 35 line blocks (32 lines of data plus 3 assorted lines of headers and spacers) then you can use readLines() to get a line at a time, skip the headers and spacers, read 32 lines of data, use strsplit() to split up data in the data lines, and so on.

Its a bit messy and relies on your file being exactly as specified (these things rarely are, you'll always find that the 143rd thing has two extra lines of guff in it) but it'll do the job.

That's just some pointers, obviously you'll need to do some work to make it work.

[Given those colnames and rownames look like lat-long, you might want to consider loading them into a raster stack using the raster package]

Comment: Hey, thanks. I looked at readLines, unfortunately, it seems to place the entire 35 block segment into a single character string when I read in the first 35 lines. There doesn't seem to be a way to convert this into a dataframe.

Comment: Easy enough to use grep, substr, the stringr package, etc. to clean it up once it's loaded into R....